# sitemap seo for multiple languages

Tags: asp.net, seo, sitemap

I am developing an asp.net 4.0 website in 4 languages. So I used an URL rewriter.

I have a mapping table in the db where I say that for home.aspx take for english Home, for another language AnotherLanguageHome and so on.

So when the page starts it checks what page it is and what culture language and replaces the *.aspx with the correct page name from the db. If the url would be www.mysite.com/Home.aspx it will become www.mysite.com/Home or www.mysite.com/FrenchHome or www.mysite.com/DutchHome and so on.

So my question is, when I create the sitemap xml file (or the robots.txt), do I have to have all the possible pages in it (www.mysite.com/Home; www.mysite.com/FrenchHome; www.mysite.com/DutchHome, and so on) or just www.mysite.com/Home.aspx?

Or is there another aproach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should include every page you want to be indexed by the search engines. If you have different URLs for different languages then those URLs must be included as well.

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused. www.mysite.com/Home; www.mysite.com/FrenchHome; www.mysite.com/DutchHome and also  www.mysite.com/Home.aspx ? or without the last one? and if so, is a sitemap generator able to do that? or it will do only the aspx pages?